# What does scene.objects.unlink really do?

Tags: python

From the [Blender Python API](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_5/bpy.types.SceneObjects.html#bpy.types.SceneObjects.unlink):

> unlink(object)   Unlink object from scene
>
> Parameters: object (Object, (never None)) – **Object to remove from
>   scene**

Does the object directly get removed from the scene or rather the ObjectBase which links to the Object and hence the Object gets removed too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It removes the object from that scene.

The reason the method is not called `remove` is that the object its self is not removed. Objects can exist in multiple scenes and groups. So scenes link to objects but don't store them (this is why you have `bpy.data.objects`).

The object-base is freed, mostly object-base is not exposed to the api, but in some cases accessing is important.

Comment: i'm interested in how blender works behind the python-api. can you point me to the c-source-file where the unlinking happens?

Comment: @ni-ko-o-kin, Scenes store a list of 'Base' types, `DNA_scene_types.h`, `struct Scene.base` is a linked list of `Base` types. `scene.c` has most functions for manipulating these. Search for `sce->base` in this file.