# Selecting and removing particular objects

Tags: python, scripting

I have a script that takes in positional data and creates a cube based on their positions. Each time I run the script, I've noticed that the old cubes are still showing up in the User Perspective. It's a pain to go through each cube and manually delete them.

I've googled for a while to find a solution to no avail. I know that

```
for ob in bpy.data.objects:
```

Allows me to iterate through the objects in the scene. I get

```
Camera
Cube
Cube.001
Cube.002
...
```

but I don't know how to use the API to select only cubes to remove and I don't know how to remove them. Is unlinking the same thing as removing the cubes from the user perspective?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should do the trick, first iterate through everything in your scene, next check if it is as mesh and check if it is a cube *(by name using the first 4 chars)*, then remove it. Also, make sure you are in *object* mode when running the script.

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene

for ob in scene.objects:
    if ob.type == 'MESH' and ob.name.startswith("Cube"):
        ob.select = True
    else: 
        ob.select = False

bpy.ops.object.delete()
```

[Unlinking an object from a scene does not remove it entirely.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2966/12)

---

Condensed version of the same script thanks to CoDEmanX.

```
import bpy    
for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    ob.select = ob.type == 'MESH' and ob.name.startswith("Cube")
bpy.ops.object.delete()
```

Comment: `ob.name.startswith("Cube")` is more efficient self-explaining, and the call to delete() can be moved outside the loop - all selected objects are deleted by a single call. Note that the delete operator will fail if in editmode! Other than that, it's the optimal solution, `bpy.data.objects.remove()` would cause trouble 'cause of users (scenes and mesh datablocks).

Comment: @CoDEmanX Thanks for the hints, need to start practising more "idiomatic blender python"

Comment: You're welcome =) Now that I think about it... Shouldn't there be an `else` clause to deselect all objects that could be selected but don't match the condition?

Comment: @CoDEmanX Another good catch ;), I would have chosen to just deselect everything prior to the loop but that's better.

Comment: It could actually be condensed to `ob.select = ob.type == 'MESH' and ob.name.startswith("Cube")`, although it's a bit less clear in the visual appearance.