# Using Blender to map XYZ objects from Homeworld RTS Space map HELP

Tags: interface

I am new to blender, and not a 3d artist.

I am making a map for a RTS game called Homeworld. The location of objects in this game are in XYZ coordinates of a 3d space. 
e.g. "Player Object,{3607, -49, -71754}"

I will be adding new objects into a large script file, the game uses, with the X,Y,Z coordinates. There are so many objects and the space is so large it is hard to visualize where everything is.

What I would like to do is create a Blender workspace that is large enough to match the in game map size, X=47866.359375, Y=27599.160156, Z=44018.109375
*NOTE: The blender does not have to be the exact same size I only need it to represent the same size so I can script in 1000's of objects and have a visual representation of where they all are relative to the 3d space.*

I would then like to enter, via script, the coordinates so what I am looking at in blender is a map of objects in 3d space.

Furthermore, I plan to add objects in blender to place objects were I want them, related to all the other objects, and then script all the XYZ coordinates to a text file that I can then place in my game map script.

*NOTE: To be clear I am not trying to get blender to make the game map. I am just using it to give me a visual representation of where the objects will be in the game.*

Writing scripts is not that difficult for me, however after 1 hour in blender I still could not enter an object at, "3607, -49, -71754" without it being so far off my visual workspace that I could not find it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello. This is not totally clear for me. You know how to script that but are not able to find your result once done ?

Comment: I am not asking about scripts. I am asking how to set up Blender to work in a space I defined so I can add objects in that space at specific coordinates. The information about script is how I plan to get information to blender from a text file and back to a text file...

Comment: ok, assuming the *models are already loaded*, so that the file to be read is "model name; x; y; z", for instance ?

Comment: you can find the various elements in these links http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6899/animate-with-position-and-orientation-from-txt-file, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31348/duplicating-non-primitive-mesh-with-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472499/blender-2-6-select-object-by-name-through-python, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8777/selecting-and-removing-particular-objects

Comment: No. Sorry for the confusion. The gist of my question is that I do not know how to setup the 3d workspace in blender to make my blender working space match that of my video games working map size. For instance, if I start a new blender session and enter an object at 47000,0,470000. The object is way off of my screen in relation to the center of 0.0.0 and I can not see the object.

Comment: So things such as 'A' to select all objects and '.' (numpad dot) to have them all in the view ? Or also, clipping in 3DView, 'N' for information panel then in it, 'view' section and set the values for 'clip/start/end' ? Or in the same information panel, set the 3D cursor position where you want them 'alt + home' to go to its position. Is that the kind of information you need ?

Comment: That helping thanks. Here is what I did. I added two cubes to Blender scene. one at 0.0.0 and the other at 25792.424.-30590. When i go to cursor position of 0.0.0 i can see 1 cube. When I try to view both at the same time I see nothing... i am guessing because they are so far apart? I tried "." on num pad and i am looking at a grey scene with no grids or cubes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some possible manipulations or information :

[image]

Misc possibilities using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in the 3D view :

[image]

Short cuts :

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> : brings back the 3D cursor to the center and places the view so that you see all objects
- <kbd>Home</kbd> : shifts the view in order to see all objects
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> : idem but make so the 3D cursor is at the center of the view
- <kbd>NumPadDot</kbd> : focus on the selection (one or several objects)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NumPadDot</kbd> : set your current view center as pivot point (Alt+'.' again to come back to normal mode)

Outliner view, to search for something and select it :

[image]

So for instance, the outline allows you to find and select one of your object, then in the 3D view, you can hit <kbd>NumPadDot</kbd> to zoom on it.

Surely I miss here many other possibilities.. but hope that helps.

Edit :

Setting the units can also help :

[image]